# React Router drops Cannot find module 'react-router/lib/HashHistory

Tags: import, syntax-error, reactjs, react-router

Using react-router and going through by the [example](https://github.com/rackt/react-router/blob/master/examples/auth-flow/app.js) provided I get `Error: Cannot find module 'react-router/lib/HashHistory'`

I have been adding to my project as it follows

```
import HashHistory from 'react-router/lib/HashHistory';
```

I'm using `browserify` for `jsx compiling`

Checking the lib folder in node_modules under react-router I do not see any of required to exist

Comment: what version of react-router are you using?

Comment: package.json says 0.13.3

Comment: upgrade to `v1.0.0-beta3`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Look at http://rackt.github.io/react-router/ for the latest stable docs (0.13.3). The examples in the github repo master branch are for the newer, unreleased version of react-router.

**Edit**: That link no longer works and now the latest stable docs *are* actually found on the master branch.
https://github.com/reactjs/react-router/tree/master/docs

Comment: what I do not find in the docs onEnter event which I would like to use for authorization